# Как присвоить style к div в зависимости от значения переменной Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть переменная `var clicks = 0`; число данной переменной меняется с каждым кликом пользователя на кнопку. Мне нужно чтобы когда значение данной переменной у пользователя было "5" и более. К `<div id="upgrade-button-5"` присваивался `style="opacity: 1;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let upgradeButton = document.getElementById("upgrade-button-5");
if (clicks >= 5) {
    upgradeButton.style.opacity = "1";
}
```